# How to add a project as dependecy?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to implement this project into my kotlin projecthttps://github.com/beraldofilippo/playerlib?

One of the steps says to "Go to Project structure and add playerlib as a dependency"

What does that mean?

Comment: Most likely, it means choose File > Project Structure from the Android Studio main menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Right click on your project in project structure on the left:[image]

2. select dependencies and click on the plus button at the bottom of the dialog and click on module dependency and choose what you need:
   [image]